# Jquery cascading dropdown, set selected item if 1 result returned

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown

I have a number of cascading jquery dropdowns on a page. Im populating them via mvc action actions in my controller on the change event of each.

All is working fine, however if a dropdown lists returns only one row (see image). The users want it to be selected by default to this item, and not have to select it themselves. Otherwise they want it to default to choose and to have to select it from a larger list.
[image]

Here is my Jquery , i imagine when i am iterating through the results function i could check if it's got one row and if so set it to the selected value. However my scripting is poor and everything i have tired hasn't worked. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    $("#ddlAddProject").change(function () {
    var projectId = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON("../Home/LoadSubprojectsByProjectId", { projectId: projectId
    },
           function (marksData) {
               var select = $("#ddlAddSubProject");
               select.empty();
               select.append($('<option/>', {
                   value: 0,
                       text: "Choose..."
               }
               ));

               $.each(marksData, function (index, itemData) {
                   select.append($('<option/>', {
                           value: itemData.Value,
                           text: itemData.Text
                   }));


           });
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one, than set the selected property to true.

```
if (marksData.length===1) {
    //select.find("option:last").prop("selected",true);
    select.find("option").last().prop("selected",true);
}
```